# If f: X → Y is a function and A ⊆ X and B ⊆ X. How do I show that f(A)\f(B) ⊆ f(A\B)?

Tags: logic

Question:
So, f: X → Y  is the same as f(x) = y
We know that A,B are both contained in X.
So f(A) and f(B) are both equal to X?
I know f(A) not f(B) then means that there's no such element found in f(B). Then how do I actually connect the dots to show that f(A\B) is true.

Comment: "$f:X\to Y$ is the same as $f(x)=y$"... *arguably*. For sure, it is **not** the same as "$f(X)=Y$".

Answer (score 1):

If $y \in f(A) \setminus f(B)$, there exists $x \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$.  Moreover, for all $z \in B$, $f(z) \neq y$, because $y \not\in f(B)$.

This means that $x \not\in B$; since it is in $A$, we conclude that $x \in A \setminus B$, and since $y = f(x)$, it follows that $y \in f(A \setminus B)$.

Taking stock, we have shown that a generic $y$ in $f(A) \setminus f(B)$ is also contained in $f(A \setminus B)$.  Hence $f(A) \setminus f(B) \subseteq f(A \setminus B)$.

Comment: why do you introduce z? Is it because of X --> Y --> Z map?

Comment: Because I want to give a straightforward translation of the formula $y \not\in f(B)$.  We say that $y$ is in $f(B)$ if there exists some $z \in B$ such that $y = f(z)$.  If $y$ is not in $f(B)$, then for all possible choices of $z \in B$ we find that $y \neq f(z)$.

Comment: @Paul24 No, it's not because of an $X \to Y \to Z$ map.  You can call that $z$ what you want.  It's just a variable to designate a generic member of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $f\colon X\to Y$ means $f$ is a function with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$. If $A$ is a subset of $X$, then
$$
f(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}
$$
or, if you want to be fussy,
$$
f(A)=\{y\in Y:\text{there exists $x\in A$ with $f(x)=y$}\}
$$

Thus you have to start with an element $y\in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ and prove it is an element of $f(A\setminus B)$.

Saying $y\in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ means $y=f(a)$, for some $a\in A$, but $y\ne f(b)$, for all $b\in B$.

If you now prove $a\in A\setminus B$, you are done. Can $a\in B$?